# Know when in 3-levels-deep ObservableCollections an item is changed, and which one

Tags: c#, events, mvvm, handler

> Foreword:
>
> The question here seems to me to be rather complex. I don't know if it
> is possible. Please if you are interested read the introductory text,
> then the code in the link provided(the question is in a forum in
> french, but the code is readable), be sure to understand it because I
> go rather deeper than it after. The problem concerns the tracking of
> changes in a hierarchy of model classes, and makes a big use of events
> and delegates. Good read!

I am building an app which manages a supermarket, with many clients accessing to the stocks of different markets( located in different places for example).

A supermarket contains many markets, each market contains (an ObservableCollection) some properties(name for example) and an ObservableCollection of shelves, each shelf contains(still same type of collection) some products and some properties, and finally each product contains some properties.

My problem is that when someone changes for example the TextBox displaying the name of the first market, thanks to databinding, the model(the first market in supermarket' ObservableCollection) is changed; and I would like to be aware of the change, in the MVVM project of the solution, and I would like to then call a web service which will change the database storing the model.

Since I do not have previous values of the model when a TextBox changes, and then when the model changes, I can't  compare the 'old' model the the 'new' one to see differences.
The second idea is to track changes(every class in the model implements INotifyPropertyChanged) and for this I found a clue : please see [this post in French (the code in the answer)](https://www.developpez.net/forums/d1371649/dotnet/developpement-windows/windows-presentation-foundation/propertychanged-observablecollection/), which shows how an ObservableCollection can raise an event when one of its items is changed(and the event keeps track of the changed item).
Provided the item has an unique Id, I can keep track of the changed items and then call the web service to change the database with only the item changed.

But To do this, I need to alter the model(by replacing all ObservableCollections by MyObservableCollections), and I think it's not recommended, the model should not contain code.

Knowing I am using MVVM(and the MVVM project does not have a reference to the WPF project), what is the best practice in this case? Should I change the model? Is it very complex to do?

thank you

EDIT

---

I coded the thing, but I have some problems.

To have clear ideas, here are The 2 lower levels of the model's hierarchy:

The products in each supermarket:

```
[DataContract]
public class ProduitMagasin : ElementSupermarche
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public int ProduitMagasinId { set; get; }

    private string _Nom;
    [DataMember]
    public string Nom
    {
        set
        {
            if (value == _Nom) return;
            _Nom = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
        get => _Nom;
    }


    private int _Quantite;
    [DataMember]
    public int Quantite
    {
        set
        {
            if (value == _Quantite) return;
            _Quantite = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
        get => _Quantite;
    }




}
```

nothing special, except that ElementSupermarche implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

These products are located in an ObservableCollectionTrack, which is my improved version of MyObservableCollection in the above http link.

here is The shelves class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Rayon : ElementSupermarche
{
    public delegate void ItemPropertyChangedHandler(object Sender, ObservableCollectionTrackPropertyChangedEventArgs e);
    public event ItemPropertyChangedHandler CollectionPropertyChanged;

    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public int RayonId { set; get; }

    private string _Nom;
    [DataMember]
    public string Nom
    {
        set
        {
            if (value == _Nom) return;
            _Nom = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
        get => _Nom;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ObservableCollectionTrack<ProduitMagasin> Produits { set; get; }

    //voir si il est appelé par new Rayon(){params}
    public Rayon()
    {
        Produits.CollectionPropertyChanged += new ObservableCollectionTrack<ProduitMagasin>.ItemPropertyChangedHandler(TrackHandler);



    }

    private void TrackHandler(object Sender, ObservableCollectionTrackPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CollectionPropertyChanged(Sender, e);
    }



}
```

Here is the ObservableCollectionTrack class:

```
public class ObservableCollectionTrack<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
    where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public delegate void ItemPropertyChangedHandler(object Sender, ObservableCollectionTrackPropertyChangedEventArgs e);
    public event ItemPropertyChangedHandler CollectionPropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollectionTrack()
        : base()
    {
        base.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(ObservableCOllectionTrack_CollectionChanged);
    }

    void ObservableCOllectionTrack_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
            foreach (T item in e.OldItems)
            {
                //Removed items
                item.PropertyChanged -= new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
                item.CollectionPropertyChanged += new ObservableCollectionTrack<ProduitMagasin>.ItemPropertyChangedHandler(TrackHandler);   <------------------------
            }
        }

        else if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            foreach (T item in e.NewItems)
            {
                //Added items
                item.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
                item.CollectionPropertyChanged += new ObservableCollectionTrack<ProduitMagasin>.ItemPropertyChangedHandler(TrackHandler);
            }
        }
    }

    void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CollectionPropertyChanged != null)
        {
            CollectionPropertyChanged(this, new ObservableCollectionTrackPropertyChangedEventArgs(sender, e));
        }
    }

    private void TrackHandler(object Sender, ObservableCollectionTrackPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CollectionPropertyChanged(Sender, e);
    }


}

//Arguments de l'évébement CollectionPropertyChanged de la classe ObservableCollectionTrack
public class ObservableCollectionTrackPropertyChangedEventArgs : PropertyChangedEventArgs
{
    public Object Item { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollectionTrackPropertyChangedEventArgs(Object Item, string propertyName)
        : base(propertyName)
    {
        this.Item = Item;
    }

    public ObservableCollectionTrackPropertyChangedEventArgs(Object Item, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        : base(e.PropertyName)
    {
        this.Item = Item;
    }


}
```

The idea is that the collection keeps track of the PropertyChanged events raised by its items, and then raises a CollectionPropertyChanged.
But there is a problem : please follow with me the flow : a product is changed; it raises PropertyChanged, which triggers in the Produits variable the event CollectionPropertyChanged; The Rayon instance will then triggers a CollectionPropertyChanged event (it reemits the same event), but Rayon instance is in a ObservableCollectionTrack collection itself, so the conclusion is that in order to be reemited again, the CollectionPropertyChanged event should be subscribed by the ObservableCollectionTrack itself!

Hence the line with the arrow in ObservableCollectionTrack (given above).
But given as this, the code doesn't work : The item is not declaring the handling of ObservableCollectionTrack.
and if I try to add that T must inherit from ObservableCollectionTrack, I get this:

[image: strange problem]

It can't convert the variable to its proper type!
Is it due to the recursivity?
Do I have to convert the ObservableCollectionTrack to an interface, more or less as INotifyPropertyChanged? Is it possible to progress and achieve this functionality(since all is nearly coded)?

thank you.

Comment: it is also simply possible to subscribe to all items, at their different levels.